# Displaying specific item from list

Tags: c#

Below is the code ive used to open a text file and store the information into a list. But im unsure how to now show a specific object on the form and how to go back and forward between them using a next and previous button.

```
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        currentfile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        saveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        Stream s1 = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s1);
        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string str = reader.ReadLine()
            c.ReadString(str);
            cars.Add(c);
        }
```

Here is the code im using to display the object however it only displays the final object in my list.

```
    private void DisplayCar()
    {
        txtBrand.Text = c.Brand;
        txtModel.Text = c.Model;
        txtYear.Text = c.Year;
        txtPrice.Text = c.Price;
        txtNumMiles.Text = c.NumMiles;
        DisplayBody();
        DisplayGear();
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Information.Count(); i++)
            str += c.Information[i] + "\r\n";
        txtInformation.Text = str;

    }
```

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Car_Manager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string currentfile;
    Car c;
    List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        c = new Car();

        saveFileDialog1.CreatePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "myText";
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter =
            "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    }

    public void clearForm()
    {
        txtBrand.Text = "";
        txtModel.Text = "";
        txtYear.Text = "";
        txtPrice.Text = "";
        txtNumMiles.Text = "";
        txtInformation.Text = "";
        radAutomatic.Checked = false;
        radManual.Checked = false;
        radConvertible.Checked = false;
        radCoupe.Checked = false;
        radEstate.Checked = false;
        radHatchback.Checked = false;
        radHPV.Checked = false;
        radSaloon.Checked = false;
        radSUV.Checked = false;


    }

    private void DisplayCar()
    {
        txtBrand.Text = c.Brand;
        txtModel.Text = c.Model;
        txtYear.Text = c.Year;
        txtPrice.Text = c.Price;
        txtNumMiles.Text = c.NumMiles;
        DisplayBody();
        DisplayGear();
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Information.Count(); i++)
            str += c.Information[i] + "\r\n";
        txtInformation.Text = str;

    }

    private void FormToObject()
    {
        c.Brand = txtBrand.Text;
        c.Model = txtModel.Text;
        c.Year = txtYear.Text;
        c.Price = txtPrice.Text;
        c.NumMiles = txtNumMiles.Text;
        BodyCheck();
        GearCheck();
    }

    private void BodyCheck()
    {
        if (radHatchback.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radHatchback.Text;}

        else if (radHPV.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radHPV.Text;}

        else if (radSUV.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radSUV.Text;}

        else if (radSaloon.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radSaloon.Text;}

        else if(radConvertible.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radConvertible.Text;}

        else if (radCoupe.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radCoupe.Text;}

        else if (radEstate.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radEstate.Text;}

    }

    private void DisplayBody()
    {
        if(c.Body == "Hatchback")
        {radHatchback.PerformClick();}

        else if (c.Body == "HPV")
        { radHPV.PerformClick();}

        else if (c.Body == "SUV")
        { radSUV.PerformClick();}

        else if (c.Body == "Convertible")
        { radConvertible.PerformClick();}

        else if (c.Body == "Saloon")
        { radSaloon.PerformClick();}

        else if (c.Body == "Coupe")
        { radSaloon.PerformClick();}

        else if (c.Body == "Estate")
        { radEstate.PerformClick();}
    }

    private void GearCheck()
    {
        if(radAutomatic.Checked == true)
        { c.GearBox = radAutomatic.Text;}

        else if( radManual.Checked == true)
        { c.GearBox = radManual.Text;}
    }

    private void DisplayGear()
    {
       if (c.GearBox == "Manual")
        { radManual.PerformClick();}

       else if (c.GearBox == "Automatic")
        { radAutomatic.PerformClick(); }
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the dialog box to open a file
        // Open a file an load the information from the file
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        // Retrieve the file name
        currentfile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        saveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        // Open the file and upload the information
        Stream s1 = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
        //  Create the steamreader reader object thanks to the stream s1
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s1);

        //  Read the first line of the streamreader object
        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string str = reader.ReadLine();


            // transform str to a football player
            c.ReadString(str);
            cars.Add(c);
        }

        DisplayCar();

        // display the football player in the form
        reader.Close();
    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save everything in a dialog box
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        // Open the file and save the information
        Stream textOut = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textOut);
        foreach (Car car in cars)
        {
            string str = c.GetToString();
            writer.WriteLine(str);
        }
         writer.Close();
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the file with the current file name
        FileStream f1 = new FileStream(currentfile,
                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(f1);
        // get the object into a string
        FormToObject();
        string str = c.GetToString();
        // write the string into the file
        writer.WriteLine(str);
        writer.Close();
    }

    private void btnAddInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c.Information.Add(txtAddInfo.Text);
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <c.Information.Count(); i++)
            str += c.Information[i] + "\r\n";
        txtInformation.Text = str;
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInformation.Text = "";
    }

    private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearForm();
    }

    private void btnPreviousCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnNextCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int a = cars.Count;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cars[2]);
    }
}

class Car
{
    //List of properties
    private string brand;
    private string model;
    private string year;
    private string price;
    private string numMiles;
    private string body;
    private string gearbox;
    private List<string> information;

    //Constructor

    public Car() //Default Constructor
    {
        brand = "Unknown";
        model = "Unknown";
        year = "Unknown";
        price = "Unknown";
        numMiles = "Unknown";
        information = new List<string>();
    }

    public Car(string str)
    {
        information = new List<string>();
        ReadString(str);
    }

    public void ReadString(string str)
    {
        string[] words = str.Split('|');
        int Nwords = words.Count();
        brand = words[0];
        model = words[1];
        year = words[2];
        price = words[3];
        numMiles = words[4];
        body = words[5];
        gearbox = words[6];
        information.Clear();
        for (int i = 7; i < Nwords; i++)
            information.Add(words[i]);
    }

    //Methods
    public string Brand
    {
        get { return brand; }
        set { brand = value; }
    }

    public string Model
    {
        get { return model; }
        set { model = value; }
    }

    public string Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        set { year = value; }
    }

    public string Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    public string NumMiles
    {
        get { return numMiles; }
        set { numMiles = value; }
    }

    public string Body
    {
        get { return body; }
        set { body = value; }
    }

    public string GearBox
    {
        get { return gearbox; }
        set { gearbox = value; }
    }

    public List<string> Information
    {
        get { return information; }
        set { information = value; }
    }

    public string GetToString()
    {
        string str = "";
        str += brand + "|";
        str += model + "|";
        str += year + "|";
        str += price + "|";
        str += numMiles + "|";
        str += body + "|";
        str += gearbox + "|";
        for (int i = 0; i < information.Count(); i++)
            str += information[i] + "|";
        return str;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a problem displaying the Information field?

Comment: The information field is part of the object and it displays fine. The problem I'm having is taking a specific object from the list and displaying it. If that makes any sense.

Comment: Probably you should pass to the DisplayCar method the object to display. It is not clear in which context you call this method. Could you show the relevant code?

Comment: Ok posted the full code hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code display Always the last car because you use Always the same variable c and add them repeteadly to the list. But this will end with a list full of the same variable which values are the ones read on the last line of your file. You should create a new instance of a Car inside the loop and add that instance to your list (this will preserve the values read on a specific line inside a different car instance)

Said that, you need an integer that keeps tracks of the current car taken from your list and displayed (I have renamed your `c` variable to a more meaningful name)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string currentfile;
    Car currentCar = null;
    int curIndex = -1;
    List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
    ....
```

And after loading the carList set this index to zero

```
....
//  Read the first line of the streamreader object
while (reader.Peek() != -1)
{
    string str = reader.ReadLine();

    // A new instance of a car at every loop
    Car c = new Car();
    c.ReadString(str);
    cars.Add(currentCar);
}

// Set the current index of the car displayed
curIndex = 0;

// take that element from the list like it was an array
currentCar = cars[curIndex];

// start the Whole process of displaying the currentCar
DisplayCar();
....

private void DisplayCar()
{
    txtBrand.Text = currentCar.Brand;
    ....
}
```

For the Navigator part and to keep it simple you could add two simple buttons  to your form and name them `cmdUp` and `cmdDown`. Add the related event handler `cmdUp_Click` and `cmdDown_Click`

```
private void cmdUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Increment and check if we are out of bounds
     curIndex++;
     if(curIndex >= cars.Count)
         // rollover to the beginning              
         curIndex = 0; 
         // (or just curIndex-- to stop at the end of the list)


     currentCar = carsList[curIndex];
     DisplayCar();
}

private void cmdDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     curIndex--;
     if(curIndex < 0)
         // rollover to the end 
         curIndex = cars.Count - 1;     
         // (or just curIndex = 0 to stop at the begin of the list)

     currentCar = carsList[curIndex];
     DisplayCar();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks very much for your help il give this a try.

Comment: Refresh the page, I have made some critical bug fix

Comment: Just letting you know the code works perfectly, thanks very much.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you show me how to save changes to an item in the list without overwriting the rest of the items? In the form of a save button.

Comment: Post a new question (and don't forget to add some code where you try to save the items) You could get a lot more of people interested to solve your (eventual) problems